# Abaqus/Python suppress warning

Tags: python, warnings, abaqus

here is a minimal example for abaqus/python, that creates a cuboid and partitions

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import __main__

model=mdb.models['Model-1']

# Sketch
s = model.ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=10.0)
s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)
s.rectangle(point1=(0.0, 0.0), point2=(5.0, 5.0))

# Part
p = model.Part(name='Part-1', dimensionality=THREE_D, type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
p.BaseSolidExtrude(sketch=s, depth=0.1)
s.unsetPrimaryObject()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p)
del model.sketches['__profile__']

# Partition
c = p.cells
pickedCells = c.findAt(((0., 0., 0.), ))
e = p.edges
p.PartitionCellByPlanePointNormal(normal=e.findAt(coordinates=(2.5, 0.0, 
        0.0)), cells=pickedCells, point=p.InterestingPoint(edge=e.findAt(
        coordinates=(2.5, 0.0, 0.0)), rule=MIDDLE))
p.PartitionCellByPlanePointNormal(normal=e.findAt(coordinates=(0.0, 2.5, 
        0.0)), cells=pickedCells, point=p.InterestingPoint(edge=e.findAt(
        coordinates=(0.0, 2.5, 0.0)), rule=MIDDLE))
```

When executing this, the following warning occurs for each partition:

> Warning: The given edge indicative point is at the center of the edge.
>   The implied edge sense will be ambiguous for some feature operations.

How can I suppress this warning or let it occur only once? Neither

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('once', 
      '.*The given edge indicative point is at the center of the edge.*',)
```

works, nor

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: good bet they are not using the standard python warning system. I don't see anything in the abaqus scripting docs re: warning control.  Here i think the warning can be safely ignored since the normal sense shouldn't affect partitioning. You could of course use a different partition method if it really bugs you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "p.InterestingPoint" command. It can better if you use directly as vertices ID. You are currently get a warrning that means there is no vertice at the related point of interes. You can try create a plane then cut it off.

Comment: This answer does not provide much information. It should be edited to explain in better details how to achieve it. Best with a code sample.